# polymorphic Avatar class Stack level too deep on build

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, associations, polymorphic-associations

I need some help with this weird error:
Got 2 classes:

```
class Avatar < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :avatarable, :polymorphic => true
  attr_accessible :photo_content_type, :photo_file_name, :photo_file_size, :photo
```

And

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  attr_accessible :location_attributes, :image_attributes, :name,
                   :location_id, :location_name, :scribble_attributes, 
                   :group_type, :privacy, :about, :membership_id, :event_id, :headline,   :avatar_attributes


  has_one :avatar, :as => :avatarable, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :avatar
```

And this is a show.html that should display avatars if they exist.

```
<% @groups.each do |g|%>
<h5>Name </h5>
<%=link_to g.name, group_path(g.id) %> <br>
<%if !g.avatar.nil?%> **also tried (g.avatar.photo.exists?)*(g.avatar.present?) (g.avatar.exists?)**
<li> <%= link_to image_tag(g.avatar.photo.url(:thumb)), group_path(g.id) %> </li> 
<%else%>
<li> <%= link_to image_tag(g.avatar.photo.url(:default_url)), group_path(g.id) %> </li> 
<%end%>
<%end%>
```

If group doesn't have an avatar I keep getting an error - **undefined method for nil:NilClass**

if I trie to do something like @Group.build_avatar on initialize or after_save, or before any check i get 
**STACK LEVEL TOO DEEP ERROR**

activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:61

**undefined method `photo' for nil:NilClass**

app/views/groups/_groupsresults.html.erb:11:in `block in _app_views_groups__groupsresults_html_erb___226577206_56390436'
app/views/groups/_groupsresults.html.erb:3:in`each'
app/views/groups/_groupsresults.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_groups__groupsresults_html_erb___226577206_56390436'
app/views/groups/index.html.erb:14:in`_app_views_groups_index_html_erb___393629073_55205484'
Please help, this is really frustrating ;/

Comment: Can you add some error trace?

Comment: If I add photos, they show up no problems, but if a group doesn't have an image, I can't even use the default_url instead which is very annoying